# Why doesn't JQuery UI autocomplete callback get called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to get the JQuery UI autocomplete to display it's choices after retrieving them from the server using Spring.  I've done a lot of seaching and tried many examples.  Hopefully I'm really close but just need some expertise to point out something obvious that's wrong with this code.  The breakpoint gets hit on the server so I know it gets that far.  The alert in the callback isn't happening so please point out the tweak that's needed.  Once I can get this super-simple example working I'll enhance it with the real data.  Thanks to anyone who can finally get me past this.

Here's the client-side code.

```
        $( "#toolTitle" ).autocomplete(
        {
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.getJSON(
                    '/workspace/autocompleteTest.html',
                    {
                        q: this.term
                    },
                    function(data) {
                        alert('hello');
                        response(data);
                    }                       
                );
            }
        }
    );
```

And here's the server-side code.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
protected List<String> autocompleteTest(@RequestParam(value="q") String q) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    json.addProperty("id", "someId");
    json.addProperty("label", "someLabel");
    json.addProperty("value", "someValue");
    result.add(json.toString());

    return result;
}
```

I really tried but finally decided that I need another pair of eyes on this one.

Comment: Could you give an actual link to the page?  It would help with debugging.

Comment: It looks like you are not using the correct format for a jQuery autocomplete.  It wants something like: `[{"id":"thing1","label":"Thing 1","value":"Thingy #1"},]`.

Comment: Thanks SuperScript for responding so fast.  The page is password-protected so let me try your suggestion about the correct format for a jQuery autocomplete.  Hopefully that'll work.  If not, let me see what I can do to let you help me.

Comment: I've updated the server-side code to return a List<String> where each one contains "id", "label", and "value".  However the alert in the callback still isn't called.  Is there anything obvious that's wrong with this?

Comment: Can you post exactly what your server is returning from `autocompleteTest.html`?  If the response is not valid JSON, `$.getJSON` will silently fail.

Comment: Here's exactly what's being returned using copy/paste after inspecting "result" in NetBeans.

result = (java.util.ArrayList) [{"id":"someId","label":"someLabel","value":"someValue"}]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50714/discussion-between-superscript-and-rob-mcallister)